# How to specify both jaxws and jaxb bindings to achieve @XmlRootElement

Tags: web-services, jaxb, wsdl, jax-ws, cxf

I've inherited a project that communicates with a SOAP-based web service. I'm a total noob at this, although have been doing Java for many years and have done a good bit with `XML`.

We have a `WSDL` file for the service, which contains the schema at the top and all the message definition stuff below. At the core of the problem, when I try to connect to the service through our code, I get the dreaded unable to marshal type "*https.api_blah_com.services.v4.Product*" as an element because it is missing an `@XmlRootElement` annotation]

My project already has a jaxws binding file:

```
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="../resources/wsdl/BlahAPI.wsdl"
  xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
  <jaxws:bindings  
    node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='https:api.blah.com/services/v4']">
    <jxb:globalBindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xjc:generateElementProperty>true</xjc:generateElementProperty>
    </jxb:globalBindings>`
  </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

Now I've read that in order to get all my Java classes generated with `@XmlRootElement`, I need to add a `jaxb:globalBinding` turning on simple mode.

I've tried adding to my local copy of the `WSDL` this:

```
<xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
    <jaxb:globalBindings>
      <xjc:simple />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
  </xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
```

But the `JAXB` compiler complains that it cannot honor this globalBindings customization because it's attached to a wrong place or is inconsistent with other bindings.

So I tried adding another bindings file, just for jaxb, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../resources/wsdl/blah.wsdl">
    <jaxb:globalBindings>
      <xjc:simple />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

But then I get an error that blah.wsdl is not part of this compilation.

I am so close to calling this service...I just cannot get past this one thing, and it's all new to me so I'm not sure what else to try.

I could split out their `WSDL` into an `XSD` and a `WSDL`? Is that required to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to bind the xsd file not wsdl at this location.  `<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../resources/wsdl/blah.wsdl">`. Please refer to section "External Binding Customization Files" at [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if JAXB Binding is configured correctly. The @XmlRootElement required if class forms the root of your element structure. However in SOAP, SOAP element would form root of the XML, Hence check if your ObjectFacory.java class is generated, if generated verify if a method is created for the class type which returns an instance of the class type for example you have `class Foo` an method `public Foo createFoo() which returns instance of Foo should be present in your ObjectFoacory.java

However I would suggest you to use CXF provided WSDL2java [this](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) with client option enabled. It takes few minutes to configure a client code